# Is it possible to define a function like this f[K[1]_,K[2]_,K[3]_]

Tags: function-construction

```
f[K[1] _, K[2] _, K[3] _] := 
 32 b^9 + 4 b^3 Cosh[b/2] K[1] K[2] - 4 b^3 Cosh[b/2] K[1] K[3]
f[10,10,10]
```

I have an equation which is a function of K[1], K[2] and K[3]. But when I have to try to evaluate at f[10,10,10]. But it is not evaluating. I don't understand what is the error. And moreover it not showing any warning and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Just write

```
 f[K1_, K2_, K3_] := 32 b^9 + 4 b^3 Cosh[b/2] K1 K2 - 4 b^3 Cosh[b/2] K1 K3
```

Comment: actually, I have written a small function from where the K1, K2, and K3 are coming. In that function I have used Table[K[i],{i,1,3}]. If I can able to express this then it would be very useful. Are there any ways to execute this?

Comment: You could do `K[x_] := Symbol["K" <> ToString[x]]`.